# variable not declared in scope and expected primary-expression before , token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I get the following error when I compile the program

> logger.cpp: In function ‘void Log()’:
>   .cpp:19:4: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
>   19 |    result = fread(Log_files, &input_event, sizeof(input_event));logger.cpp:19:42: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
>   19 |    result = fread(Log_files, &input_event, sizeof(input_event));

```
#include <iostream>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
struct input_event event;

void Log(){
    fstream Log_file;
    Log_file.open("/dev/input/event", fstream::app);
    FILE * Log_files = fopen("/tmp/data.txt", "w");
    if(!Log_files){
        cout << "Datei /tmp/data.txt nicht geöffnet";
    }
    if(Log_file.is_open()){
        bool session = true;
        while(session){
            result = fread(Log_files, &input_event, sizeof(input_event));
            if(result != Log_files);
            cout << "Reading error";
       }
    }
}
int main(){
    Log();
    if(event.type == EV_KEY && event.value == 0){
        switch(event.code){
            case 30:event.code = KEY_A;break;
                cout << "A" << event.code;
            case 14:event.code = KEY_BACKSPACE;break;
                cout << "\t" << event.code;
            default:
                cout << "No";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You use `result` in `result = fread(Log_files, &input_event, sizeof(input_event));`, but you have never declared a variable called `result`.

Comment: Not directly related, but you're going to have a bad time with `if(result != Log_files);` which definitely doesn't do what you want

Comment: you are right bro i defined it now

Comment: yeah i see that to i cant compare a pointer and a variable thanks to u but i still have the second error and sry for my english it is my 3 language

Comment: You forgot to add a type for `result` at this point: `result = fread(Log_files, &input_event, sizeof(input_event));` I am not familiar with the linux api but I think you need to add `string` before `result`.